# This isn't returning the same reference when using Castle Proxies with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle

I'm having some trouble where returning "this" is somehow returning a different reference/type when using castle proxies with nhibernate. 
Castle is 2.5.2.0 and NHibernate is 3.1.0.4000

```
public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Node Me() { return this; }
}

public static void SomeMethod()
{
    var node = session.Load<Node>(1)
    var me = node.Me()
    //ReferenceEquals(node, me) // false
    //node == me // false
    //node.GetType().Name // NodeProxy
    //me.GetType().Name // Node
    me.Id = 88;
    // node.Id == 88 // true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected behavior. See my blog post, [Hacking lazy loaded inheritance](http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2010/08/hacking-lazy-loaded-inheritance.html).

Comment: Can't you copy the relevant part of your blog in your answer?